# How 100% sure exclude Android application from tv?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have a general question which I failed to find answer to. How make sure, that application(in my case widget) not being ever available for installation on Android TV. I get weird crashes and report that it doesn't work, but only later noticed, that crash is cauzed by Sony Bravia TV failing to request permission to modify system settings.

Is there any way to exclude app from installation on TV deviced? App have to install only on all phones and tablets, but no TV's.

Thanks!

Error arrived to Google Play Console. It's shouldn't be available at all to TV devices.

```
Sony BRAVIA 4K 2015 (SVP-DTV15), 2560MB RAM, Android 6.0


android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1798)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1512)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:3930)
  at y.startActivityForResult (BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:67)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:3890)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:720)
  at com.sapphire_project.screenwidget.MainActivity$1.onClick (MainActivity.java:57)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5204)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21153)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Does the phrase `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` occur in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html).

Comment: No, it doesn't occur